# react-router " Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

i am quite new to react and react-router.

Problem with react is here that, on some pages of my application react-router is working and some giving error like this: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

i am using react 0.14.1

My routing code looks like this:

```
render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Loginpanel}/>
  <Route path="Index" component={Index}/>
  <Route path="Form" component={Form} />
  <Route path="Checkindex" component={Index}/>

  <Route path="Signup" component={Signup}/>
  <Route path="Admin" component={Admin}/>
  <Route path="AdminEditDetails" component={AdminEditDetails}/>
  <Route path="AdminDetails" component={AdminDetails}/>


</Router>,
document.getElementById('js-main'));
```

My component is like this now:

```
class  App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {      
      comments: AppStore.getAll();
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {  
    var length = this.state.comments.length;
    var firstnumber = length - 4;

    if(length == 0){
      console.log("here comes");
      this.props.router.push('/');
    }
    else{
      console.log('work normally');
    }
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app does not have an instance of Router in its props which is giving you `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

I'm assuming you're importing withRouter to get the instance of the Router so you'd need to wrap the component in that if you still want to use that... (example [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options) but not suggested)

Instead, a better approach to programmatically navigating is to use

`import { hashHistory } from 'react-router;'
...
hashHistory.push('/');` in your `componentWillMount` lifecycle event.

The docs are [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

Hope this helps!

Comment: `hashHistory` is no longer supported, you will get `Attempted import error: 'hashHistory' is not exported from 'react-router'`

Comment: That documentation link is now dead.

Answer (score 15):

Using `hashHistory` directly from `react-router` is certainly an option, but it makes unit-testing a bit more painful.
Browser history will generally not be available in the context tests run in and it's easier to mock out a prop than to mock out a global API.

Consider using the `withRouter` higher-order-component that `react-router` provide (since `v2.4.0`).

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {

    (...)

}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Your `App` class will receiver `router` via props and you can safely do `this.props.router.push('/');`.

Comment: Is this a better approach than the accepted answer?

Comment: @Doug I think so, personally, which is why I posted it but YMMV :)

Comment: Any link explaining usage of `hashHistory`. Can you please also give some link explaining first paragraph, mainly mock part. Quite new to react and web development in general.

Answer (score 10):

If you are use Partial Component and calling it like `<Header />` then you should  replace it by `<Header {...this.props} />`

Answer (score 1):

You are using hashHistory. The following code should work.

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';
hashHistory.push('/');
```

The root route should also be defined.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below code see if your `router props` is working or not

```
componentWillMount() {

var length = this.state.comments.length;
var firstnumber = length - 4;
if(length == 0){
    console.log("here comes");
  if(this.props.router !== undefined) {
    this.props.router.push('/');
  } else {
    console.log(this.props.router);
  }
}
else{
    console.log('work normally');
}
}
```

also you can visit their documentation to get more information from below url
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the `history` prop from `witRouter` higher order component, and use the [push method on the `history` object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) to push the route you want to.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class App extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        ...
        this.props.history.push('/');
        ...
    }

}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Add two lines.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
this.props.history.push("/welcomePage");
```